# How to make difference between file and directory in mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've used **mod_rewrite** in my application. So I have some pages like `site.com/about/` and `site.com/services/` that are files actually. But I have a directory named **panel** for administration panel.
How can I write mod_rewrite rules to exclude this directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to check that the rule won't match files and directories with this two rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

See also the official documentation from [rewritecond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> - '-**d**' (is directory)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
> - '-**f**' (is regular file)
>     Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.